# Shrinking LVM physical volume on top of mdadm degraded RAID array, adding a spare and rebuilding it

Tags: debian, lvm, mdadm

I have a `Debian Wheezy` system with a couple of 500 GB HDDs in RAID-1 (`mdadm` mirror), on top of which sits `LVM` logical volumes with 5 partitions (`boot`, `root`, `usr`, `var` and `tmp`), total size of 47.15 GiB. 418.38 GiB in the physical volume are free. `GRUB` installed on both drives.

One of HDDs failed and now array is degraded, but data is intact.

What I want is to swap all of these 2 HDDs to 80 GB SSDs without the need to reinstall the system from scratch. The subtle point here is that I need to shrink LVM physical volume to match SSD's size, but logical volumes are not contiguous (there is a lot of a free space in the beginning), so I have to somehow move logical volumes within a physical one. And there is no `lvmove` command in Debian.

How do I achieve this?

Some console output:

**Versions:**

```
root@wheezy:~# uname -a && mdadm --version && lvm version
Linux wheezy 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.63-2+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
mdadm - v3.2.5 - 18th May 2012
  LVM version:     2.02.95(2) (2012-03-06)
  Library version: 1.02.74 (2012-03-06)
  Driver version:  4.22.0
```

**Array details:**

```
root@wheezy:~# mdadm -D /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Thu Dec  4 12:20:22 2014
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 488148544 (465.53 GiB 499.86 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 488148544 (465.53 GiB 499.86 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Thu Dec  4 13:08:59 2014
          State : clean, degraded 
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : wheezy:0  (local to host wheezy)
           UUID : 44ea4079:b3b837d3:b9bb2ca1:1b95272a
         Events : 26

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       8       16        0      active sync   /dev/sdb
   1       0        0        1      removed
```

**LVM brief details:**

```
root@wheezy:~# pvs && vgs && lvs                                                                                               
  PV         VG     Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree                                                                                          
  /dev/md0   system lvm2 a--  465.53g 418.38g                                                                                        
  VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree                                                                                            
  system   1   5   0 wz--n- 465.53g 418.38g                                                                                          
  LV   VG     Attr     LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Copy%  Convert                                                            
  boot system -wi----- 152.00m                                                                                                       
  root system -wi-----   2.00g                                                                                                       
  tmp  system -wi-----  10.00g                                                                                                       
  usr  system -wi-----  20.00g                                                                                                       
  var  system -wi-----  15.00g
```

**Segmentation of the PV:**

```
root@wheezy:~# pvs -v --segments /dev/md0
    Using physical volume(s) on command line
    PV         VG     Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree   Start  SSize LV   Start Type   PE Ranges             
    /dev/md0   system lvm2 a--  465.53g 418.38g      0 89600          0 free                         
    /dev/md0   system lvm2 a--  465.53g 418.38g  89600    38 boot     0 linear /dev/md0:89600-89637  
    /dev/md0   system lvm2 a--  465.53g 418.38g  89638   512 root     0 linear /dev/md0:89638-90149  
    /dev/md0   system lvm2 a--  465.53g 418.38g  90150  5120 usr      0 linear /dev/md0:90150-95269  
    /dev/md0   system lvm2 a--  465.53g 418.38g  95270  3840 var      0 linear /dev/md0:95270-99109  
    /dev/md0   system lvm2 a--  465.53g 418.38g  99110  1280          0 free                         
    /dev/md0   system lvm2 a--  465.53g 418.38g 100390  2560 tmp      0 linear /dev/md0:100390-102949
    /dev/md0   system lvm2 a--  465.53g 418.38g 102950 16226          0 free
```

Comment: Or you could just create a new RAID/VG/LV on the SSD and `rsync` your files over. It's not online but likely to be faster than anything else.

Comment: At first I should shrink both PV and array. Then I just recover the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to shrink the pv or rebuild the array.  You just need to create a new array out of the new drives and add that as a new pv ( `pvcreate` + `vgextend` ), then `pvmove` all of the existing lvs off the old pv, then remove the old pv ( `vgreduce` ) and take that drive out of service.

Comment: Good alternative solution but I prefer to stick to the old array just to save time: I don't want to reintegrate a new array in the old system.

Comment: @TranslucentCloud, it takes *less* time to create a new array than to resize the old one, rebuild it on one of the new drives, remove the old drive, and rebuild it again.

Comment: But you can face additional steps trying to install `GRUB` from the Live system. It's easier to boot into production system and install GRUB from it with one simple command.

Comment: @TranslucentCloud, who said anything about a live system?  Either way you have to install grub on the new drives.  Since you are running debian that is pretty easy: `dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc` and select the new drives.

Comment: Okay, but how do you expect me moving LVs on running production system? The filesystems on these LVs are mounted and used. To boot into Live system is unavoidable step when you messing around with system volumes. Prove me wrong.

Comment: @TranslucentCloud the whole point of LVM is the ability to resize and move things while the system is in use. Same for MD, you may replace disks and resize while it's running. The only thing that could prevent you is if your filesystem does not support live resize (if you had to shrink it).

Comment: @frostschutz the filesystems are within LVs, so they should be left intact. I will test if what you suggest will work on actual working system, after setting a test system in the virtual environment.

Comment: @TranslucentCloud, like frostschutz said: that is the point of lvm.  I have `pvmoved` my root volume from old drive to new multiple times over the last few years, while it is mounted.

Comment: @psusi sounds impressive, didn't knew that, thanks for clarification. I will mark your answer as a solution, because it seems really most efficient and easy.

Answer (score 3):

It's not `lvmove` but `pvmove`.

```
pvmove --alloc=anywhere /dev/md0:89600-102950 /dev/md0:0-12070
```

That should move any extents within the 89600-102950 range to 0-12070 range. According to the data you posted that should result in your LVs being relocated to the beginning of your PV.

Comment: Yes, this resolves `LV` aligning part of the task.

Answer (score 3):

**ATTENTION: THIS GUIDE IS FAR FROM OPTIMAL. CHECK THE ACCEPTED ANSWER**

Okay, I've figured out how to do what I tried to. This will be a some kind of a tutorial.

During this time I didn't yet realized, that  manipulations with LVs are actually *possible* when the filesystems are mounted and booted into some `live` Linux distro (SystemRescueCD). People here explained me, that there is no necessity in this if you're not manipulating with actual filesystems and just aligning LVs and shrinking PV.

So with this guide you'll definitely achieve what you want, but not in an efficient way, because it confronts the very LVM's nature — possibility to do things *live*.

1. Due to non-contiguous nature of logical volumes on my physical volume, I should somehow to move them in the beginning of the physical volume. The `pvmove` command, as being suggested by @frostschutz can move `LVs` within a `PV`:

   ```
   root@wheezy:/home/a# pvmove --alloc=anywhere /dev/md0:89600-102950 /dev/md0:0-12070
   /dev/md0: Moved: 100.0%

   root@wheezy:/home/a# pvs -v --segments /dev/md0
       Using physical volume(s) on command line
     PV         VG     Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree   Start SSize  LV   Start Type   PE Ranges          
     /dev/md0   system lvm2 a--  465.53g 418.38g     0     38 boot     0 linear /dev/md0:0-37      
     /dev/md0   system lvm2 a--  465.53g 418.38g    38    512 root     0 linear /dev/md0:38-549    
     /dev/md0   system lvm2 a--  465.53g 418.38g   550   5120 usr      0 linear /dev/md0:550-5669  
     /dev/md0   system lvm2 a--  465.53g 418.38g  5670   2560 tmp      0 linear /dev/md0:5670-8229 
     /dev/md0   system lvm2 a--  465.53g 418.38g  8230   3840 var      0 linear /dev/md0:8230-12069
     /dev/md0   system lvm2 a--  465.53g 418.38g 12070 107106          0 free
   ```
2. Now `PV` is ready for shrinking to the SSD's size (80GB). 80 gigabytes are actually a 80000000000 bytes:

   ```
   root@wheezy:/home/a# pvresize --setphysicalvolumesize 80000000000B /dev/md0
     Physical volume "/dev/md0" changed
     1 physical volume(s) resized / 0 physical volume(s) not resized

   root@wheezy:/home/a# pvs
     PV         VG     Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree 
     /dev/md0   system lvm2 a--  74.50g 27.36g
   ```
3. After this, I can resize the array itself. There are no filesystems on this level, so I end up with just single `mdadm --grow` command, which can actually be used to shrink arrays too. The size should be entered in `kibibytes`, so it is 80000000000 / 1024 = 78125000:

   ```
   root@wheezy:/home/a# mdadm --grow --size=78125000 /dev/md0
   mdadm: component size of /dev/md0 has been set to 78125000K

   root@wheezy:/home/a# mdadm -D /dev/md0
   /dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Thu Dec  4 12:20:22 2014
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 78125000 (74.51 GiB 80.00 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 78125000 (74.51 GiB 80.00 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 1
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Thu Dec  4 17:56:53 2014
             State : clean, degraded 
    Active Devices : 1
   Working Devices : 1
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

              Name : wheezy:0  (local to host wheezy)
              UUID : 44ea4079:b3b837d3:b9bb2ca1:1b95272a
            Events : 60

       Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
          0       8       16        0      active sync   /dev/sdb
          1       0        0        1      removed
   ```
4. Now it's time to add an existing SSD to the array and let it rebuild:

   ```
   root@wheezy:/home/a# mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sdc
   mdadm: added /dev/sdc

   root@wheezy:/home/a# cat /proc/mdstat 
   Personalities : [raid1] 
   md0 : active raid1 sdc[2] sdb[0]
         78125000 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
         [>....................]  recovery =  1.3% (1081920/78125000)         finish=11.8min speed=108192K/sec

   unused devices: <none>
   ```

After rebuilding I have a healthy array. Its members can be swapped around and installation of GRUB can be routinely performed (after booting into production system) with `grub-install /dev/sdc`.

Comment: I hope you didn't make your PV too large; if the SSD is 80GB, you may not be able to set your PV to 80GB what with offsets due to partitioning and metadata. Also, of course this is an online operation, all of it, no live cd necessary.

Comment: @frostschutz, as you probably have seen, I've not set my PV to 80 gigabytes, but to 74.5 gibibytes (step 3) and this is a sufficient space to match SSD's size. Also, the LVs are mounted and used by the system, so I had to boot into some live system.