# How can I make LV start from 0 of VG

Tags: ubuntu, lvm

I am trying to resize my LVM partition. I resized my LV, but when I trying to resize LVM partition, it says `cannot resize to 1363 extentds as later ones are allocated.`. I checked https://askubuntu.com/questions/252204/how-to-shrink-ubuntu-lvm-logical-and-physical-volumes, After I executed pvmove, pvs says my root volume not starts from 0, but at 65244. So I can't resize the lvm partition. How Can I make root volume starts from 0?

Comment: exact commands and outputs? from what you are describing, `pvmove --alloc=anywhere` is the correct approach, this is mentioned in the linked question https://askubuntu.com/a/604302/161981 , also another example https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171472/30851 here you see later extents specifically moved to 0

Comment: I saw other post, at https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=68712#p288620. It seems to exactly same as your link. Thanks for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's resolved. I used command that like to `pvmove (dev):a-b (dev):0-c`. It's now starts from 0.